# ERROR: Unrecognized Go version

Tags: go

I am installing go1.5 with gvm v1.0.22
and getting the following error:

```
gvm install go1.5
Updating Go source...
ERROR: Unrecognized Go version
```

Comment: Do you have a working 1.4 install? 1.5 is compiled with go, so you need 1.4 to compile 1.5.

Comment: @mrd0ll4r installed 1.4, same error

Comment: And I guess you `gvm use` that go1.4 too? There are mutiple issues about this on github, for example [this](https://github.com/moovweb/gvm/issues/166) and [this](https://github.com/moovweb/gvm/issues/160), so that's where I got the idea... Anyways, you could still install the binaries with the `-B` flag, i guess?

Comment: Yep, thank you much anyway!

Comment: Oh, another idea: What about `gvm install go1.5.1` ?

Comment: Although not a direct solution, https://github.com/travis-ci/gimme may be an alternative tool to gvm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installed successfully after reinstalling gvm

```
gvm implode
gvm install go1.4
gvm use go1.4
gvm install go1.5
```

Comment: I'm not sure what implode does, but I did not need to run that first. Neither did I have to reinstall gvm, just run the above commands (except for implode).

Comment: @fgblomqvist implode removes gvm.